# execute a task after kendo grid loaded successfully in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have two methods in button click event, I want to execute a method after kendo grid loads successfully.

```
$("#search").click(function(result) {
  $('.btn-spin').button('loading'); //this two are loading simultaneously
  getAdditionalData();
  // $("#systemusergrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
  $("#facilitygrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page(1);
  $("#facilitygrid").css("display", "block");
  $('.btn-spin').button('reset'); //this two are loading simultaneously, I want this line to run after grid completely loaded
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Register [`dataBound`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/databound) event handler. Do it outside of you click handler as you need it only once.

```
var grid = $("#facilitygrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.bind("dataBound", function(event) {
    $('.btn-spin').button('reset');
});
```

Comment: It is not working for me, i am using it in jquery   $("#search").click(function () {
          $('.btn-spin').button('loading');
          
    var urlLink=  $("#facilitygrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page(1);
         $.ajax({
         url: urlLink,
         success: function(resp){
            $('.btn-spin').button('reset');
         },
        error: function(){
             $('.btn-spin').button('reset');
        }
        });
   });
    }); //this works for me fine but its not stoping at the same time when databound occours

Comment: I cannot gues what 'is not working for me'. Make some minimal verifiable and executable example of your issue to have a reference to start investigation from.

Comment: Custom.js:228 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Custom.js:228)
    at fire (jquery-1.9.1.js:1037)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.js:1148)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.9.1.js:433)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.9.1.js:103)

Comment: kendo grid load and databound are two different things.  I read this question as executing a method after the kendo grid inititalizer function is called